# Error while adding dynamic text in html Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, dynamic-html

I am getting an issue while adding some text dynamically, its goes replaced. Here is my code

in html file

```
<textarea #messageInput></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="sendMessage(messageInput.value)"></a>
```

in ts file

```
export class className{

 flag :boolean=false;

   newMessage: any;

  sendMessage(msg:any) {

   this.flag=true

   this.newMessage=msg

 }

get flagVar(){
  return this.flag
}
```

}

in the same component html file I am trying to display as like

```
<div *ngIf='flagVar'>
<label  [hidden]="!forwardOption">
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" >  
 </label>
  {{msg}}
</div>
```

Instead of adding its replaced every time.

any help?

Thanks

Comment: Where you displaying newMessage?

Comment: Declare newMessage as array like     newMessage = [];

Comment: @PareshGami code edited..

Comment: You need to display all typed message in html something like that?

Comment: @PareshGami yes, I want to display multiple message on same html file

Comment: @PareshGami same I tired without ngModal, didn't worked

Comment: You need to use [(ngModel)] for 2-way binding. If you have to clear variable value using viewChild or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need a *ngFor for repeat your messages.
The code you need to change:

Here is an online [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxirm4)

**HTML FILE:**

```
<textarea #messageInput></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="sendMessage(messageInput.value); messageInput.value = ''">Add Message</a>

<div *ngIf="mesasgeList.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let msg of mesasgeList">
    <label [hidden]="!forwardOption">
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" >  
 </label> {{msg}}
</div>
</div>
```

**TS FILE:**

```
export class AppClass {
flag: boolean = false;
  forwardOption: boolean;
  mesasgeList = [];
  sendMessage(msg: any) {

    this.flag = true;
    this.forwardOption = true;
    this.mesasgeList.push(msg);

  }

  get flagVar() {
    return this.flag
  }
}
```

Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take array if you want to more then one value. You cannot use the single variable for that.

Here I am taking 2 variable. `msg` which is a `two-way` type of variable so when user type and save it we push a value of that in an array and make it blank easily and in HTML I am using `ngFor` so you can easily display values of array

You can try the really simple example.

### ts

```
newMessage = [];
msg = '';
sendMessage() {
    this.newMessage.push(this.msg)
    this.msg='';
}
```

### html

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="msg"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="sendMessage()">Click Here</a>


<p *ngFor="let m of newMessage">
  {{m}}
</p>
```